# how install figma on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I don't have the opportunity to install figma on my ubuntu 18.04

After install figma I have error:

```
/snap/figma-linux/2/figma-linux: error while loading shared libraries:
 libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: issue ...  apt-file search libpng16.so   ...  to show packages which contain that file then install one of them

Comment: @scott-stensland, there is only `libpng16-16` package, which is already installed by default. Despite that `figma-linux` does not run.

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered above errors however I did manage to launch it on ubuntu 19.04 using

download the binary file from

https://github.com/ChugunovRoman/figma-linux/releases

on Ubuntu pick one called

> figma-linux_0.5.1_amd64.deb

who has direct link https://github.com/ChugunovRoman/figma-linux/releases/download/v0.5.1/figma-linux_0.5.1_amd64.deb

once downloaded install using

```
sudo dpkg -i figma-linux_0.5.1_amd64.deb
```

On Ubuntu 19.04 I get this

```
Selecting previously unselected package figma-linux.
(Reading database ... 253481 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack figma-linux_0.5.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking figma-linux (0.5.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of figma-linux:
 figma-linux depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package figma-linux (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 figma-linux
```

so now issue

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install -y 
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1   libdbusmenu-gtk4  
sudo dpkg -i figma-linux_0.5.1_amd64.deb
```

then upon first launch you will get this error (see workaround)

```
scott@berghia ~/Downloads $ figma-linux   
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/scott/config/figma-linux/Settings'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:436:3)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as openSync] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:160:31)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1168:35)
    at Object.writeFileSync (/opt/figma-linux/resources/app.asar/node_modules/jsonfile/index.js:117:13)
    at Settings._ensureSettings (/opt/figma-linux/resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-settings/lib/settings.js:153:18)
    at Settings._readSettings (/opt/figma-linux/resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-settings/lib/settings.js:192:10)
    at Settings._getValueAtKeyPath (/opt/figma-linux/resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-settings/lib/settings.js:281:22)
    at Settings.get (/opt/figma-linux/resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-settings/lib/settings.js:404:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/figma-linux/resources/app.asar/main/main.js:1:18900)
    at o (/opt/figma-linux/resources/app.asar/main/main.js:1:279)
```

so pure guesswork I created its missing config file using

```
mkdir -p ~/config/figma-linux
touch ~/config/figma-linux/Settings
```

finally it launched OK with a

```
figma-linux
```

have fun